# ¿Stack Overflow en Español funcionará exactamente como Stack Overflow?

Tags: discusión

Me parece que esta es una pregunta básica, ya que StackOverflow (en Inglés) funciona bajo ciertas reglas específicas que creo que la propia comunidad de es.StackOverflow debiera definir por su cuenta.

Las que me vienen primero a la mente son:

- Lo que se considera off-topic, sobre todo cuándo son preguntas relacionadas con IT, pero no necesariamente de programación. En Inglés, se tiene la alternativa de sitios de la red donde el tema estaría dentro del tópico, como SuperUser, ServerFault, etc. (creo que se debe ser más tolerante, al menos mientras se completa la red de sitios en Español)
- Preguntas que tienen respuestas subjetivas o que invitan solamente al debate, pero no hay una respuesta canónica sobre el tema. Por ejemplo, "cuál es el mejor de X", o "recomendarme libros de Y" (creo que se debe funcionar igual que SO en Inglés en este tema).

Es super excitante la idea de que este sitio por fin vea la luz, aprovecho la oportunidad aquí para darle la bienvenida a todos los participantes de la beta, tanto privada como pública.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo. De momento se puede ser más tolerante con el "off-topic" pero no con la calidad de las preguntas.

Comment: Por mi parte, creo que sería importante tratar de mantener SO en español sin preguntas "off-topic" para poder lograr un sitio de calidad y no diluirlo como un repositorio de cualquier tipo de preguntas relacionadas con tecnología, sino que para desarrolladores. El hecho que no haya otros sitios en español aún no significa que debamos "abrir" tanto las restricciones

Answer (score 16):

Recuerdo que leí en algún lado (ya no recuerdo dónde... en Area 51 Discussion, on tal vez Meta.SO... no sé. Si puedo encontrar el enlace, lo añadiré aquí), que cada sitio, incluyendo los XX.stackoverflow.com, tiene su propio fase de "beta" para definar la comunidad, lo que está en tema y fuera de tema, etc.

Aunque eso es una versión nueva de un sitio existente, no puede ser exactamente igual (solo en otro idioma).  Un gran razón es que no hay sitios hermanos dónde podemos migrar preguntas.  Así, es posible (pero no presumido) que queremos responder a una gama de preguntas más ancha que en el sitio inglés.

También con una nueva comunidad, vamos a tener otras diferencias. Somos diferentes personas, desde diferentes culturas, con niveles diferentes de educación, etc, etc, etc.  Los problemas de SO en inglés que han provocado algunas reglas, normas y otras decisiones en SO en inglés, no necesariamente van a existir aquí.

Creo que lo más prudente es definir nuestras normas propias, con las de SO en inglés como guía, pero nada más que una guía.  Siempre es mejor preguntar aquí en Meta que asumir que la regla de SO en inglés sigue aquí.

Comment: Respecto a tu última frase: de hecho yo asumiría que funcionamos como el SO inglés, *a menos que se especifique lo contrario*.

Comment: El comportamiento de las comunidades, sea la de Inglés, o Español son comunidades diferentes, diferentes formas de pensar, es claro que en cuanto a pagina web, todo funcionaría igual, pero en cuanto a comunidad, jamás sería igual. Por eso personalmente yo diría que no funciona exactamente como StackOverflow Inglés.

Answer (score 0):

Es cierto que tenemos menos usuarios que en el sitio en ingles, porque tenemos gente de menos países que habla español, mientras que la mayoría de los hispanohablantes que entramos a Stack Overflow lo hacemos porque sabemos ingles. Por esto es que tenemos menos participación y también podemos concentrar mejor los temas que en ingles se separan en diferentes sitios de programación. Pero desde donde lo veo tendríamos que concentrarnos en que los sitios *deberían ser útiles a presente y futuro* para las personas que lo visitan buscando soluciones.

En este sentido, deberíamos aceptar preguntas que sean:

- Requerimientos de software o cualquier cosa aceptada en programmers.SE.
- Problemas técnicos específicos de código según se acepta en SO.
- Revisión de código (funcionando) para optimizarlo o aplicarle cosas como principios SOLID. Esto se acepta en codereview.
- Tal vez, y solo tal vez, recomendaciones de software bajo exactamente las normas de softwarerecs.SE (evitando pollings intencionales).

Es decir: deberíamos poder comportarnos como esos sitios en ingles antes de que se rompan en diferentes sitios relacionados a programación.

La norma fundamental: *el funcionamiento del sitio debe ser útil para los usuarios que preguntan como para los que buscan en google*. me gustaría saber que mi respuesta fue útil para evacuar alguna duda, y me gustaría encontrar una respuesta a una duda que tengo, y no simplemente un *Por que se me rompe esto?*, aunque tal vez eso involucre una ayuda con un fragmento de Rails con el que yo mismo este enojado, pero tal vez me sea el cuádruple de trabajo darme cuenta que se trata del mismo problema, por tener que elucidar el foco del mismo de entre toda la maraña de código.

Comment: relacionado http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/q/161/25