# Causa de cierre por no ajustarse a alcance definido en el Centro de Ayuda

Tags: característica-nueva

Estoy viendo que muchas preguntas reciben la mayor parte de votos de cierre por ser *"demasiado amplia"* (eg: [¿Cómo puedo mejorar este código para que funcione?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/13500/c%c3%b3mo-puedo-mejorar-este-c%c3%b3digo-para-que-funcione)) que, junto con el *"no estar claro lo que se pregunta"*, parece ser un comodín para todo.

En mi opinión, la razón principal para cerrar esta preguntas debería ser por *"no ajustarse al alcance definido en el centro de ayuda"*. En el [centro de ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), se especifica tres tipos de preguntas **no pertinentes**, incluso si entran en la temática de la *Programación*:

- Preguntas en busca de asistencia con la depuración (eg: "¿por qué no
  funciona este código?")
- Preguntas acerca de un problema que ya no puede ser reproducido (eg:
  error tipográfico)
- Preguntas solicitando ayuda con trabajo escolar

Creo que todas estas preguntas deberían cerrarse principalmente por estar **fuera de alcance**. El problema que veo es que en la opciones de cierre, la opción por estar fuera de alcance pone literalmente:

> **no relacionado porque...**
>
> Esta pregunta no parece versar *sobre programación*, dentro del alcance definido en el centro de ayuda.

Creo que esta redacción da pie a confusión. Aunque sí que la pregunta vaya de programación, puede que siga estando fuera de alcance por ser uno de los tres casos *no pertinentes* enumerados en el Centro de Ayuda.

Propongo simplificar la redacción de la causa de cierre para que sea simplemente:

> **no relacionado porque...**
>
> No se ajusta al alcance definido por el centro de ayuda.

Comment: Voté para cerrar la pregunta relacionada y, en efecto, también considero que se presta para malinterpretaciones el motivo de cierre.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo en ambas cosas: en cerrar la pregunta y en cambiar el motivo del Off Topic.

Answer (score 3):

La pregunta que colocas [¿Cómo puedo mejorar este código para que funcione?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/13500/227) es válida para el sitio, está explicado aquí: [Definición de la temática apropiada para el sitio](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/164/227). Al parecer, muchos usuarios todavía no comprenden que **esta comunidad en español tiene sus propias reglas** y **no tiene las mismas reglas del sitio en inglés**. Todo parte por aquí.

Así como debemos educar a los "nuevos" usuarios de la comunidad a publicar publicaciones dentro del alcance del sitio, los usuarios que votan a cerrar una pregunta (para que se ponga en espera y luego se cierre) deben conocer también las reglas que decidimos en comunidad. Muchos usuarios venimos de la comunidad en inglés y pensamos que este sitio debería tener un reglamento parecido y sentimos que debemos ser igual de estrictos con los usuarios de esta comunidad. Esto **no es así**, y se explica en la primera pregunta del Meta: [¿Stack Overflow en Español funcionará exactamente como Stack Overflow?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1/227).

Si tuviésemos que cambiar la redacción, yo propongo que sea así:

> **no relacionado porque...**
>
> Esta pregunta no parece versar sobre programación, revisión de código, diseño de aplicaciones u otro dentro del [alcance definido por la comunidad](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/161/227) ni del centro de ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Me parece correcto que la comunidad defina su propio alcance, pero el enlace, aunque clarificador, no es lo suficientemente concreto.

Por ejemplo, ¿todas las respuestas con votos positivos son parte del alcance o solo las preguntas con más de 10 votos a favor, o solo las 3 primeras? **El alcance debe ser tan claro *y específico* que no admita interpretaciones**.

Adicionalmente, y un poco al margen, este tipo de preguntas [Definición de la temática apropiada para el sitio](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/161/definici%C3%B3n-de-la-tem%C3%A1tica-apropiada-para-el-sitio) que evidentemente afectan al gobierno de sitio deberían funcionar como un sistema de votación: ejemplo, durante dos meses la pregunta estará abierta y las respuestas que obtengan más de 10 votos se incluirán dentro del alcance de la comunidad.