# ¿Se considera una pregunta "no pertinente" por las mismas razones que en el StackOverflow inglés?

Tags: discusión, cierre-de-preguntas

Aun soy nuevo a este sitio. Tengo mas tiempo usando StackOverflow en inglés.  Y me estoy dando cuenta de que tengo que tener cuidado en cuanto a asumir que las cosas funcionan de forma idéntica en los 2 sitios.  De hecho me sirvió leer [¿Stack Overflow en Español funcionará exactamente como Stack Overflow?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1/stack-overflow-en-espa%C3%B1ol-funcionar%C3%A1-exactamente-como-stack-overflow) para entender mejor ese punto. Mi objetivo a corto plazo es de tomar el tiempo necesario para ponerme al día con las entradas en Meta a fin de tener una mejor idea del consenso de esta comunidad.

Con esto en mente, mi duda concierne la pregunta siguiente (y otras similares a esta): [¿De qué trata la técnica “bottom-up”?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/28688/de-qu%C3%A9-trata-la-t%C3%A9cnica-bottom-up). Básicamente, la persona está pidiendo una explicación de A a Z sobre un tema en particular. En otras palabras, está pidiendo un tutorial.

En StackOverflow inglés, hay precisamente una razón de cierre para las preguntas en busca de un tutorial ([Ver razón #4](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)). Pero me parece interesante que la misma página de ayuda en español no incluye esta razón para cerrar una pregunta ([Ver: ¿Sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)).

¿Quiere decir esto que este tipo de preguntas en busca de un tutorial es aceptable en StackOverflow en español?  O, ¿se consideraría que la pregunta es demasiado ámplia, aun si no hay una razón de cierre que aplique específicamente a las preguntas en busca de un tutorial?

**Edición**: Me acaba de dar cuenta que ya existía esta pregunta: [Falta el punto 4 del artículo “¿Sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?” del Centro de Ayuda](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/248/falta-el-punto-4-del-art%C3%ADculo-sobre-qu%C3%A9-temas-puedo-preguntar-aqu%C3%AD-del-centr). Si desean cerrar esta pregunta como duplicado, está bien. Pero noto que no hubo mucha discusión en aquella pregunta, así que tal vez deseen comentar más al respecto.

Comment: Las razones de cierre no son las mismas pues el sitio en español esta en beta y esta basado en el template que se usa para sitios en beta. las funciones que estan habilitadas en el sitio en ingles, son diferentes o mejor dicho son mas.  Hasta donde se, @JuanM -el CM de SOes-, ha comentado que cuando el sitio se gradue podremos pedir este tipo de cambios (ej agregar un motivo de cierre), mientras tanto nos tendremos que conformarnos con lo que hay.

Comment: Personalmente, no considero que el OP esté pidiendo un tutorial para la pregunta que indicas. Basta con una respuesta muy concisa sobre qué es Bottom-Up y qué es Top-Down tal como se ha provisto ahora. Ahora, yo no vería mal si alguien quisiera proponer todo un tutorial como respuesta, eso he visto en muchos casos en SOen. Colocar todo un muro puede ser un gran aporte, eso lo decidirá la comunidad con los votos a favor.

Comment: @rnd: Pregunta tonta, pero donde se puede ver que el sitio está en beta? No tenía idea al respecto.

Comment: @Luiggi: Dudo que OP esté conforme con una respuesta concisa, como la que hay ahora. Pero puede que yo esté completamente equivocado. Creo que la duda que en realidad tengo (aplique o no al ejemplo que dí) es: ¿generalmente, son aceptables las preguntas amplias? Lo que creo percibir de ti y otros en la comunidad es que, ese tipo de preguntas en realidad no son mal vistos aquí. ¿Estoy en lo correcto? Y si es así, cuando se usaría la razón de cierre "muy amplio"? De paso, gracias por tu excelente trabajo en este sitio!

Comment: @sstan puedes verlo en Area51. http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/42810/stack-overflow-in-spanish

Comment: @sstan yo pensaría que eso se lo dejemos al OP, no es bueno pensar por otros :)

Comment: @sstan ahora, sobre las preguntas amplias, todo depende. Para mí, esa pregunta no es amplia, puede tener una respuesta concisa. Ojo que yo no considero "esta respuesta el OP no la aceptará", esa es harina de otro costal. Obviamente, no siempre vamos a coincidir en esto. Para ello, puedes votar a cierre y la comunidad votará si coincide contigo.

Comment: @Luiggi: Me parece muy bien lo que dices.  Iré aprendiendo poco a poco a discernir las situaciones correctamente. Gracias.